# Adobe Flex collapsible panel in flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, panel

i am quite new to Adobe Flex and im currently trying to build a collapsible Panel as Sidebar (sidebar extends panel) for my mobile application. My problem is, that the [tutorial](http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/09/creating-collapsible-panel-in-flex-4/) I followed , was built with Flex 4 and I am using 4.6. 
However, I have no errors, only a warning, telling me that "the CSS Typeselector of my SidebarPanel component wasn't processed, because the type is not used in the application."

I tried to run it, but all my Flexbuilder does, is showing a normal blank panel, without a button, change the skinstate. The point where I am stuck, is the grouping of all title bar layers and adding the button. I did both, but still got the blank panel.

I put the "titleBarGroup" from the tutorial arround "contents", "topGroup","tbHilite", "tbDiv" and "titleDisplay" and the "collapseButton" after the "contents"-group.

SidebarPanelSkin.mxml:

```
   <!-- layer 3: contents -->
<!--- Contains the vertical stack of titlebar content and controlbar. -->
<s:Group id="titleBarGroup" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"
         maxHeight="32" rotation.collapsed="90">
    <s:Group left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="contents">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
        </s:layout>

        <!--- @private -->
        <s:Group id="topGroup" mask="{topGroupMask}">

            <!-- layer 0: title bar fill -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                        <s:GradientEntry color="0xE2E2E2" />
                        <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                    </s:LinearGradient>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <!-- layer 1: title bar highlight -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="tbHilite" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                        <s:GradientEntry color="0xEAEAEA" />
                        <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
                    </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

            <!-- layer 2: title bar divider -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="tbDiv" left="0" right="0" height="1" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="0xC0C0C0" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <!-- layer 3: text -->
            <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#titleDisplay -->
            <s:Label id="titleDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
                     left="9" right="3" top="1" bottom="0" minHeight="30"
                     verticalAlign="middle" textAlign="start" fontWeight="bold">
            </s:Label>



        </s:Group>  
        <s:Button id="collapseButton" width="16" height="16" top="7" right="7"
                  label="-" label.collapsed="+" toolTip="Collapse" toolTip.collapsed="Open" />
</s:Group>
```

main.mxml:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:cc="customcomp.*"
               xmlns:customskins="skins.*" applicationDPI="160" xmlns:skins="skins.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Platzieren Sie nichtvisuelle Elemente (z. B. Dienste, Wertobjekte) hier -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import skins.SidebarPanelSkin;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace cc "customcomp.*";
        @namespace customskins "skins.*";

        customskins|SidebarPanel{
            skin-class: ClassReference('skins.SidebarPanelSkin');
        }

    </fx:Style>

    <cc:SidebarPanel id="collapsiblePanel" >

    </cc:SidebarPanel>

    </s:Application>
```

Is the error resulting from my not processed typeselector or is there another error in my code? Another question is, whether there are any docs on transitioning from Flex 4 to 4.6. Found some stuff concerning 3 to 4.6, but not much more.

Greets,

oaten_cracker

Comment: Solved the problem. I forgot to set the skinClass to the component -.- sorry for bothering you..